MSBuild - csproj - Use combinations to exclude folder from build
In order to allow building our projects in Visual Studio and a Linux DevContainer side-by-side, I changed the build configuration of our project as follows:
Directory.Build.props
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS.StartsWith(`Windows`))' == 'true' ">
    <MSBUildProjectExtensionsPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName)\obj-windows\</MSBUildProjectExtensionsPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName)\bin-windows\</BaseOutputPath>
    <NoWarn>MSB3539</NoWarn>    <!-- Temporary Suppress warning about BaseIntermediateOutputPath -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(OS.StartsWith(`Windows`))' != 'true' ">
    <MSBUildProjectExtensionsPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName)/obj-linux/</MSBUildProjectExtensionsPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName)/bin-linux/</BaseOutputPath>
    <NoWarn>MSB3539</NoWarn>    <!-- Temporary Suppress warning about BaseIntermediateOutputPath -->
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

This redirects bin files to bin-windows or bin-linux respectively. Same for the obj folder.
The problem with this is that this includes these folders in the .NET compilation

Which causes a recursive tree if you'd do alternating builds on windows/linux

I can solve this by adding the following snippet to my csproj file
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="bin-linux\**" />
    <Compile Remove="bin-windows\**" />
    <Compile Remove="obj-linux\**" />
    <Compile Remove="obj-windows\**" />
    <Content Remove="bin-linux\**" />
    <Content Remove="bin-windows\**" />
    <Content Remove="obj-linux\**" />
    <Content Remove="obj-windows\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="bin-linux\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="bin-windows\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj-linux\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="obj-windows\**" />
    <None Remove="bin-linux\**" />
    <None Remove="bin-windows\**" />
    <None Remove="obj-linux\**" />
    <None Remove="obj-windows\**" />
</ItemGroup>

However I would like to write it like this instead
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="**\(bin|obj)-(linux|windows)\**" />
    <Content Remove="**\(bin|obj)-(linux|windows)\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="**\(bin|obj)-(linux|windows)\**" />
    <None Remove="**\(bin|obj)-(linux|windows)\**" />
</ItemGroup>

But this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?
I created a repository here

I'm puzzled by the behavior of your project. SDK projects have Default includes and excludes and the $(BaseOutputPath) should be excluded. There are Default item inclusion properties for controlling/customizing the include/exclude. The recursive directories behavior is strange. Try replacing $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(MSBuildProjectName) with $(MSBuildProjectDirectory) .

Regular expressions are not supported to select files, only globbing patterns.
You can concatenate these globbing patterns via a semicolon.
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="bin-linux\**;bin-windows\**;obj-linux\**;obj-windows\**" />
  <Content Remove="bin-linux\**;bin-windows\**;obj-linux\**;obj-windows\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="bin-linux\**;bin-windows\**;obj-linux\**;obj-windows\**" />
  <None Remove="bin-linux\**;bin-windows\**;obj-linux\**;obj-windows\**" />
</ItemGroup>

Or in case your project doesn't have any other folders with a bin- or obj- prefix, then you might consider below one, where any folder starting with bin- and obj- gets excluded.
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="bin-*\**;obj-*\**" />
  <Content Remove="bin-*\**;obj-*\**" />
  <EmbeddedResource Remove="bin-*\**;obj-*\**" />
  <None Remove="bin-*\**;obj-*\**" />
</ItemGroup>

